# I don't understand C++ pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, pointers, integer, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following program which defines 2 integers and a pointer to an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int bla=999;
    int a=42;
    int* pa=&a;

    printf("%d \n", *pa);
    printf("%d \n", pa);

    pa++;
    //*pa=666; //runs (no error), but the console is showing nothing at all

    printf("%d \n", *pa);
    printf("%d \n", pa);

    pa++;
    //*pa=666; //runs and changes the value of *pa to 666;

    printf("%d \n", *pa);
    printf("%d \n", pa);

}
```

The output is:

42

2686740

2686744

2686744 //this value is strange, I think

999

2686748

The adresses are making sense to me, but the fourth value is strange, because it is exactly the adress of the int. Can somebody explain that behaviour ?

When I comment *pa=666 (the first apperance) in, the console shows nothing, so here is some sort of error, but the compiler does not show an error. Maybe this is because of the size of int on my system, I have a 64bit-windows-os, so maybe the int is 64 bit and not 32 ? And because of that the *pa-value is 999 after the second increment and not the first ?

I am sure, there are a lot of C-programmers out there who can explain what is going on :)

Comment: Pointer increments are based on the pointee's type size.

Comment: By the way, the compiler gives warnings for the %d, but this is not important for me :)

Comment: Why ignore the warning? It tells you that `%d` isn't for printing pointers, `%p` is.

Comment: I know, but when you use %p, it would give a hex and you would not see the effect of value==adress

Comment: Then just print the integers in hex as well

Comment: Ok, I could probably do that

Comment: Please give your question a decent title when posting here. SO is meant to be searchable and have others profit from the answers you get. Formulating your question properly would be a first step of understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is not strange, it is to be expected: You have three variables in `main()`, all of which are stored on the stack, and which happen to be right one after the other. One of these variables is the pointer itself. So, when you dereference the pointer in the third line, you get the current value of the pointer itself.

Nevertheless, this output is not predictable, it is undefined behavior: You are only allowed to use pointer arithmetic to access data within a single memory object, and in your case, the memory object is just a single `int`. Consequently, accessing `*pa` after the first `pa++` is illegal, and the program is allowed to do anything from that point on.

More specifically, there is no guarantee which other variables follow a certain variable, in which order they follow, or if there is accessable memory at all. Even reading `*pa` after the first `pa++` is allowed to crash your program. As you have witnessed, you will not experience a crash in many cases (which would be easy to debug), yet the code is still deeply broken.

Answer (score 5):

```
int* pa=&a;
```

`pa` is pointer to an integer and accessing `*pa` is defined.

Once you increment your pointer, then the pointer is pointing to some memory(after p) which is not allocated by you or not known to you so dereferencing it leads to undefined beahvior.

```
pa++;
```

`*pa` is UB

Edit:

Use proper format specifier to print the pointer value `%p` as pointed out by @haccks

Comment: The pointer is now pointing to a garbage-value, but why is that value exacly the pointer-adress ?

Comment: @Andre Incrementing a pointer makes your pointer point to the memory location after `p` and that is fine. So when you print it you will get the memory location after `p` which is `p= p+1` When you dereference it than you don' know what is stored in that location so UB

Comment: I would expect 0 or some garbage-value, but not exactly the memory-adress as the value. Is that an coincedence ?

Comment: @Andre When you try to print some memory address how to do expect it to be `0`? You pointer holds some address and your `printf()` is printing it no it is not a coincidence

Comment: I have no problem with the memory-adress, I have a problem with the value at that memory-adress.

Comment: @Andre All the answers here including my answer makes a point that dereferencing a pointer `p` after incrementing is UB why bother about what you get , when we say UB we can't explain what is happening

Comment: This answer is not very satisfying because it does not explain the effect. There has to be a way to explain this. I will search for it later :)

Comment: @Andre ATB for your effort :)

Comment: To me it sounds really strange that the value is the memory address, meaning that there's probably a better explaination to it (whether it has to do with the compiler or something else) than "unexpected behaviour" (as if ANYTHING could have happened). I think the asker wanted an answer which explains why it behaves like it does, even if it's not necessarily something that's recommended to do. And from my experience, most people just tell these people "not to explore" those areas since it's wrong, even though it's nothing but a matter of curiosity (I've experienced this myself before).

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong format specifier to print address. This will invoke undefined behavior and once the UB is invoked, all bets are off. Use `%p` instead.

```
printf("%p \n", (void *)pa);
```

Another problem is that after execution of `pa++;`, you are accessing unallocated memory and another reason for UB.

Answer (score 2):

You're not smarter than your compiler.

As said by another answer what you do is Undefined Behaviour. With `pa` you are just doing non-sense, it does'nt correspond to any reasonlable algorithm for a defined goal: it's non sense.

However I will propose you a possible scenario of what's happenning. Though much of it could be false because compilers do optimizations.

```
int bla=999;
int a=42;
int* pa=&a;
```

These variables are allocated on the stack.

When writing `pa = &a` you say "I want pointer `pa` to be equal to the address of `a`".

Probably the compiler could have allocated the memory in the order or declaration, which would give something like:

- `bla` would have address 0x00008880
- `a` would have address 0x00008884
- `pa` would have address 0x00008888

when you do `pa++` you're telling: move my pointer of int to the next position of int in memory.
As ints are 32 bits, you're doing `pa = pa + 4bytes` i.e. `pa = 0x00008888`

Notice that, *by chance !*,you're probably pointing to the address of the `pa` pointer.
So now the pointer `pa` contains its own address... which is pretty esoteric and could be called [ouroboros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros).

Then you're asking again `pa++`... so `pa = pa + 4 bytes` i.e. `pa = 0x0000888c`

So now you are probably accessing an unknown memory zone. It could be an access violation. It's undefined behaviour if you ever want to read or write.

Answer (score 1):

When you first assigned the pointer it pointed to `2686740`. The pointer is an integer pointer and integers use 4 bytes (usually, on your machine it used 4). That means `pa++` is going to increase the value to be 4 more which is `2686744`. Doing it again resulted in `2686748`

If you were to look at the resulting assembly code the order of your local variables would be switched around. The ordering was `a`, `pa`, `bla` when the code ran. Because you don't have explicit control over this ordering the output of your printing is considered to be undefined

After the first time you did `pa++` the pointer pointed at itself, that is why you got the "strange value"

As mentioned by many of the other answers, this is not good use of pointers and should be avoided. You don't have control over what the pointer is pointing to in this situation. A much better use of pointer arithmetic would be pointing at the beginning of an array and then doing `pa++` to point to the next element in the array. The only problem you could experience then would be incrementing past the last element of the array

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is platform dependant and printing the pointer value using `%d` is undefined behavior

Comment: That is true but usually it is 4 and on his machine it is 4

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to increment the value in `a` through the pointer `*pa`?

If so, do: `(*pa)++`. The brackets are crucial as they mean "take the value of the pointer", then use that address to increment whatever it is referencing.

This is completely different to `*pa++` which simply returns the value pointed to by `*pa` and then increments the *pointer* (not the thing that it is referencing).

One of the little traps of C syntax. K&R has a few pages devoted to this, I suggest you try some of the examples there.